# Can any browser be configured to whitelist certain sites and blacklist the rest?

Tags: browser, blacklist

I was thinking of creating a VM that is behind a firewall that blocks all traffic except to my banks.  So, I can't access any other website and no one but the bank can get at me; so yeah, a online banking VM.  Is there a way to implement this in one of the major browsers?  A browser that prevents the user from navigating to any other site besides the banks' sites?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but Chrome and Firefox are opensource so there is nothing stopping you from adding that "feature".

Comment: This is what firewalls do.  This can be accomplished with either hardware of software firewalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that with Google Chrome/Chromium. Look for the URLWhitelist policy

http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#URLWhitelist